# Send email with images embedded in body html c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I've this method to send email with images embedded in a body text and it works in almost all clients, except in Outlook. It doesn't show the images outlook but it does in outlook web. Someone help?

here you have the method

```
public static void SendNotificationMail(string subject, string message, string emailTo, string ccTo, string bccTo, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a message and set up the recipients.
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(AppConfig.EmailFrom, AppConfig.EmailFromDisplayName);
            msg.To.Add(emailTo);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccTo))
            {
                msg.CC.Add(ccTo);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bccTo))
            {
                msg.Bcc.Add(bccTo);
            }
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = message;
            // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
            //string contentID = "@std";
            String imagesPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "images";
            String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath);
            foreach(String imageFile in files){
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(imageFile);
                // create the INLINE attachment
                Attachment inline = new Attachment(file.FullName);
                inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
                inline.ContentId = "@"+file.Name;
                inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/jpg";
                inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(imageFile);
                //Utility.PrintMessage("Attachment" + file.Name + " ==> " + file.FullName);
                msg.Attachments.Add(inline);
                // replace the tag with the correct content ID
                //msg.Body = msg.Body.Replace("@@IMAGE@@", "cid:" + contentID);
            }
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            //Send the message.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(AppConfig.SMTPServer);
            // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            try
            {
                Utility.PrintMessage("Sending notification e-mail to: " + emailTo);
                client.Send(msg);
                Logger.WriteTNSLog(subject + " - " + emailTo);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.WriteAppLog(e.Message, "Utility.SendNotificationMail()");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: `catch (Exception) { }` stop doing this!  You're silently throwing away valuable exception information

Comment: If you are at a point where you can handle the exception, then catch it and do some action based on the exception. If you can't handle it and don't want to log it, then don't bother catching it in the first place! Let it bubble up to somewhere that you can handle it.

Comment: Sorry. My bad about the exception. Can you help about my main concern?